# How to create a matrix of matches of vector elements across columns of a table

Tags: r, apply

In a simulation I have a population, here `Participants`, and I draw samples from it. To be precise, I generate all possible combinations of (sub-) samples.

```r
Participants <- letters[1:4]
SampleSize   <- 2
SubSamples <- combn(Participants, SampleSize)
SubSamples
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "c" 
#> [2,] "b"  "c"  "d"  "c"  "d"  "d"
```

Needed is a new table or data frame that has a
row for each participant and shows TRUE/FALSE in each column
if the according participant is part of the sub sample of
this column or not. That is a matrix with
`choose(length(Participants), SampleSize) =`
6 columns. In our example, it would look like this:

| T | T | T | F | F | F |
| T | F | F | T | T | F |
| F | T | F | T | F | T |
| F | F | T | F | T | T |

Apply did not work (obviously).

```r
apply(SubSamples, 2, `%in%`, Participants)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

It does the comparison in the wrong “direction”. It does `SubSamples %in% Participants` when it should be
an apply over `Participants %in% SubSamples`. But, of course, when we switch the arguments this does not give me a table but only one single result for each participant.

```r
sapply(Participants, `%in%`, SubSamples)
#>    a    b    c    d 
#> TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised the problem lies in the fact that I need a result with the dimensions of the second argument when `apply` functions give me a result with the dimensions of the first argument. That is why I tried a function that switches the arguments of `'%in%'(x, table)`. So, the solution was surprisingly simple:

```r
Participants <- letters[1:4]
SampleSize   <- 2
SubSamples <- combn(Participants, SampleSize)
```

```r
apply(SubSamples, 2, function(x, y) y %in% x, Participants)
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
#> [1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> [3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#> [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Is this the only solution?

<sup>Created on 2021-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>